# How to count multiple objects inside nested array sequentially in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array structure like this :

```
const array = [
    [
        {
            "item": { "name": "item1" },
            "property": { "name": "property1" }
        },
        {
            "item": { "name": "item2" },
            "property": { "name": "property2" }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "item": { "name": "item3" },
            "property": { "name": "property3" }
        }
    ]
]
```

If I run this command in pure Javascript:

```
let count = 0
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        count ++
        console.log(count)
    }
}
```

Then the output will be like this :

```
1,2,3
```

I want to be able to generate the output like above using `array.map()` in ReactJS and keep those sections. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
    {array.map((nestedArray, arrayIndex) => (
        <div key={arrayIndex} className="array-list">
            <h1>Group: {arrayIndex+1}</h1>
            {nestedArray.map((items, nestedArrayIndex) => (
                <p>Item: {nestedArrayIndex+1}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    ))}
    </div>
)
```

And this is the render output (using my css styles):

[image]

What is an effective and short way to do it?

I hope I have explained everything clearly

Comment: **FYI:** This happens because of ```key``` attribute on the ```div```. If you remove the ```key``` then it will show as you want it to but React will throw an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep those sections I think the easiest thing would be to use a variable to keep track of the count. You can then use `map` to iterate over `array` and its arrays, updating count as each new array is encountered.

To do that you should separate out the code into a function that you call from your component's `return`.

```js
const array=[[{item:{name:"item1"},property:{name:"property1"}},{item:{name:"item2"},property:{name:"property2"}}],[{item:{name:"item3"},property:{name:"property3"}}]];

function Example({ data }) {

  function createJSX(data) {

    let count = 0;

    return array.map((arr, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Group: {i + 1}</h3>
          {arr.map(obj => {
            ++count;
            return <p>Item: {count}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      )
    });

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {createJSX()}
    </div>
  );

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={array} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="react"></div>
```

And then call the function from your `render`:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    {createJSX()}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this.

```
const array = [
  [
    {
      item: { name: "item1" },
      property: { name: "property1" }
    },
    {
      item: { name: "item2" },
      property: { name: "property2" }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      item: { name: "item3" },
      property: { name: "property3" }
    }
  ]
];

 <div className="container">
    {array.flat().map((item, arrayIndex) => (
       <p>Item: {arrayIndex + 1}</p>
    ))}
 </div>
```

You will need to flatten your array first, then all children will be in one array.

Comment: The problem with flattening is that OP has sections/groups in their returned output, and flattening the array will remove those sections

Comment: Thanks mate! This is my first answer on the site :D

Comment: @NickParsons You're right. It really depends on if they want to keep those sections still.

Comment: @RyanLe just like Nick Parsons said, the above method removes this element  `<div key={arrayIndex} className="array-list" />` and I need it to separate between groups of items. But the method above gave me new knowledge, so thank you for that. But still, it is not the right answer for my case.

Comment: Hey @FarhanPradanaTallei. I add another solution bellow

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want to keep track of those sections:

```
render() {
  let indexCount = 0;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {array.map((nestedArray, arrayIndex) => (
        <div key={arrayIndex} className="array-list">
          {nestedArray.map((items, nestedArrayIndex) => (
            <p key={(indexCount += 1)}>Item: {indexCount}</p>
          ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

}

You will need a variable to save the current indexCount then just simply increase it each time you render the final index. Also, I added a missing key to your child nestedArray render.

Just a side note is that it's not recommended to use array indexes as render list keys.

Comment: `render` won't be applicable if the OP is using a functional component.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the method above is good and by my wishes. But that answer had already been similarly preceded by Andy. I'm waiting for a better answer, but there doesn't seem to be one. Once again, thank you so much

Comment: Appreciate your kindness @FarhanPradanaTallei

Comment: @FarhanPradanaTallei I've updated my answer with a working React example based on your data.

Comment: @Andy great! it becomes better